# gazebo_ros_control missing in latest ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
When running "catkin_make" , I got "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_ros_control" with any of the following names"

From Gazebo website, http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing,
they mentioned that "Note: currently in ROS Jade there is no ros-jade-gazebo-ros-control package released."

From http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing, "The 2.5.3 Jade version will include the gazebo_ros_control: ros/rosdistro#11044".

However,
is there any way I can either

1. build gazebo_ros_control from the source code and install in my local jade (/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks)
2. ignore gazebo_ros_control

Thank you for taking time on my questions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233391/gazebo_ros_control-missing-in-latest-ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs/) by [willSapgreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26619/willsapgreen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the response from Stack Overflow and verified the response work.

The solution is git clone gazebo_ros_control from its repo (http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_control) and put it under your catkin_ws/src and catkin_make.

Please leave your comment if any question or suggestion.

---

Originally posted by [willSapgreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26619/willsapgreen/) with karma: 61 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-05-07**:
Please link to the stack overflow question so others can benefit from reading that answer if they want.

**Comment by [willSapgreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26619/willsapgreen/) on 2016-05-14**:
Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974607/gazebo-ros-control-missing-in-latest-ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs/36990037#36990037

Thank you for reminding me, @tfoote